# VB.NET Static Constructor Not Called in DLL

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, inheritance

I've got a VB.NET project that has 2 classes like this. One Base and one derived that are contained in a seperate project DLL.

```
Public Class BaseClass
    Public Shared label_ As String
End Class

Public Class Derived
    Inherits BaseClass

    Shared Sub New()
        BaseClass.label_ = "Some Label"
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub Dump()

    End Sub
End Class
```

And to test this code I've created

```
Sub Main()

    'Shared label is Nothing here?
    Console.WriteLine(Derived.label_)

    'Shared label is assigned here as shared constructor is called
    Derived.Dump()
    Console.WriteLine(Derived.label_)

End Sub
```

I am finding that the Shared Constructor in the derived class is only called when I call an instance method or call any other static method?

My understanding is that the Shared Constructor is called when the application is run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced, not when the application is run.

You can't know the exact moment in with the shared constructor will be called, and you should'nt make assumptions about it, but MSDN ensures that points:

1. Shared constructors are run before any instance of a class type is
   created.
2. Shared constructors are run before any instance members of a structure type are accessed, or before any constructor of a structure.Type is explicitly called. Calling the implicit parameterless constructor created for structures will not cause the shared constructor to run.
3. Shared constructors are run before any of the type's shared members
   are referenced.
4. Shared constructors are run before any types that derive from thetype are loaded.
5. A shared constructor will not be run more than once during a single
   execution of a program.